# Laravel-Mix 8 with run watch

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5, npm, webpack

I want to load vue Component in Public file using npm run watch , it gives me a message in watch dev or build ..?

```
        Node.js v14.15.0.
        npm 6.14.8
        Laravel Installer 4.1.0
        npm run watch
        > @ watch C:\Users\ANOOD\Desktop\Laravel&vueja\Laravel_vue
        > npm run development -- --watch
        
        
        > @ development C:\Users\ANOOD\Desktop\Laravel&vueja\Laravel_vue
        > cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"
        
        The system cannot find the path specified.
        events.js:292
              throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
        
        Error: spawn node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js ENOENT
            at notFoundError (C:\Users\ANOOD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
            at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\ANOOD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
            at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\ANOOD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25) 
            at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
        Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
            at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\ANOOD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37) 
            at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
          code: 'ENOENT',
          errno: 'ENOENT',
          syscall: 'spawn node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js',
          path: 'node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js',
          spawnargs: [
            '--progress',
            '--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js',
            '--watch'
          ]
        }
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
        npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
        
        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     C:\Users\ANOOD\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-10T12_23_34_863Z-debug.log
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR! 
        npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
        npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
        
        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     C:\Users\ANOOD\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-10T12_23_35_071Z-debug.log
```

Comment: "_Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?_" You did run `npm install` before, did you?

Comment: yes I did that  also the node_modules is already built in the Laravel Envorment , but still the problom goes every single time

Answer (score 0):

The problom was not on Laravel or npm or node_modules , simply it was the directory that I have been use when I put my laravel Project in Laravel every thing is ok but when I move it to another Directory calls Laravel&Vue it won't work and this problem apper.